# Assign data types to each column of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let us say I have two large data frames, one for which I store the data as character and one for which I specify the data type of each of the columns for the given data frame.

For example:

```
my.df = data.frame(
    id = c('122','345', '43'), 
    name = c('john','matt','roger'), 
    race = c('1','2','1'), 
    age = c('20','23','34'), 
    height = c('6.4', '5.7', '4.9')
) 

cols.of.my.df.type.df = data.frame(
    col.name.in.my.df = c('id','name', 'race', 'age', 'height', 
    c('string', 'string', 'integer, encoded value', 'integer', 'decimal')
)
```

The type in `cols.of.my.df.type` is not the same as in R, but I am also looking for recommendations in which R data type I should also specify the columns.

Is there a fast way to transform the data types of `my.df` to the ones specified in `cols.of.my.df.type`?

Comment: Well, a better question is why are they all coming in as character values to begin with. R should know better when you do `read.table` unless you have funny values in your data. How clean is your data?

Comment: That's a good point, but in my case I'd rather not let R decide but read all as some default type (character in this example) and then transform according to the specified data types.  My files are huge and they come with specify data types, much like in SQL when one defines the data types.

Comment: Use `colClasses` in `read.table`. Faster and acheives your stated goal. Personally I prefer to use stringsAsFators=FALSE since factors ha a complete hassle up to the point where you've done all your transformations and aggregation and are ready to submit the data to regression functions.

Comment: Then just specify the correct `colClasses=` value during import. See `?read.table` for more detauls

Comment: @BondedDust that's a good suggestion, but sadly I do not know the column names in advance, and they are in different order in the real data I have... that is why I'd like to transform them using the column names.

Comment: Then use `readLines()` with a limit of one line to get the values before using `read.table`. Which now leaves me irritated that you are not posing this question accurately. You have a text file and you need to illustrate the question with a realistic version of the file rather than screwing around with stuff where you have mangled the data at input and are then asking us to unmangle it.

Comment: @BondedDust you can get `read.table()` to read only a few or one line of data too. With the rest of your comment, I fully agree. Few things as frustrating on [so] as people trying to be helpful but ending up only presenting a fraction of the problem leading to endless back and forths in the comments.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I mostly agree. Though on a side comment, I understand that the problem can be solved with read.table but I am very surprised that there's not an easy way to achieve this ONCE the data frame has been read into R.  I am still curious on how to do this once the data frame has been read to be fair...

Comment: @Dnaiel there is a relatively simple one, but not something hardcoded in R upfront; you can get close using `'storage.mode<-'()` (the replacement version of `storage.mode()`, but that doesn't handle factors. You can probably do what you want using `storage.mode()` and `as.factor()` for the factors. However, the better thing to do would be to sort this out before you read in everything. Hence suggestions to read a few lines, work out how to map variables to data types, and then read in the data correctly with `read.table()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c('122','345', '43'), 
    name = c('john','matt','roger'), 
    race = c('1','2','1'), 
    age = c('20','23','34'), 
    height = c('6.4', '5.7', '4.9'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 

cols <- data.frame(
    name = c('id','name', 'race', 'age', 'height'),
    type = c('string', 'string', 'integer, encoded value', 'integer', 'decimal'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is one way to do what you want, assuming a set-up as per the above. Note that `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is important in the above definitions for this to work.

```
foo <- function(i, data, colInfo) {
  ## mapping your types to R's types
  RTypes <- c(string = "character", `integer, encoded value` = "factor",
              integer = "integer", decimal = "double")
  ## get current type
  TYPE <- colInfo$type[i]
  ## match this against the mapping vector
  RTYPE <- RTypes[TYPE]
  ## if a factor coerce via as.factor
  if (RTYPE == "factor") {
    out <- as.factor(data[, i])
  } else { ## otherwise convert via storage.mode()
    out <- data[,i]
    storage.mode(out) <- RTYPE
  }
  out # return
}

tmp <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(cols)), foo, df, cols)
names(tmp) <- names(df)
tmp <- data.frame(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tmp
str(tmp)
```

Which gives:

```
> tmp
   id  name race age height
1 122  john    1  20    6.4
2 345  matt    2  23    5.7
3  43 roger    1  34    4.9
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id    : chr  "122" "345" "43"
 $ name  : chr  "john" "matt" "roger"
 $ race  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1
 $ age   : int  20 23 34
 $ height: num  6.4 5.7 4.9
```

Comment: Might I suggest to rename `foo` to something like `retype_data` or something more readble ...

Comment: @agstudy I'll leave that up to the OP - I'm not very imaginative when it comes to names of functions I don't intend to use or wish to just apply as an anonymous function but doing it inline would be clutter.

Comment: This answer helped me find the term "factor" to describe expected values coded as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a coercion function ( same technique is used with db driver):

```
MyType2RType <- function(obj,...)
{
  switch(obj ,
         "decimal"="numeric",
         "integer, encoded value"="factor",
         "integer"="integer",
         "string"= "character")
}
```

You can use it like this for example ( it is not a complete solution , but just a hint based on comments)

```
cols = list(
  name = c('id','name', 'race', 'age', 'height'),
  type=  c('string', 'string', 'integer, encoded value', 'integer', 'decimal')
  )

read.table(...,colClasses= sapply(cols$type,MyType2RType))
```

Comment: thanks! this helps but is half of my question, the other half is how to now re-assign the data type to each column in the R data frame.

Comment: @Dnaiel if you know ahead of reading in the data, agstudy's answer helps you avoid reading the data in in the wrong format initially, hence no need to re-assign. If you must re-assign after the fact, add `as.` to the `"numeric"` types etc on the right hand side of `=` in `MyType2RType` and arrange for the function with that name to be called.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks I see, so you'd call MyType2RType in an apply function with the as.

Comment: @Dnaiel actually, I'd probably use `storage.mode()` for all but the factors, which would simplify things a little.