# R transpose dataframe with logical variables

Tags: r, dataframe, types, transpose

I'd like to transpose a dataframe which has logical and numeric variables in a row without losing the datatype information (i.e. without the TRUE/FALSE being turned to 1/0)

Here is my code:

```
xx <- data.frame(
  v1 = 200,
  v2 = 2,
  v3 = FALSE
)

#   v1 v2    v3
# 200  2 FALSE

t(xx)

#   [,1]
#v1  200
#v2    2
#v3    0
```

Instead I'd like to get:

```
t(xx)

#   [,1]
#v1  200
#v2    2
#v3    FALSE
```

My final gaol is to display the dataframe in shiny with rhandsontable in order to modify it and then save it in a csv file. Since I have a dataframe with many columns and only 2 rows, I want to transpose the data for better visualization. Before saving I transpose them back again.
What can I do?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: The 'issue' is that a vector can only contain a single type (numeric or logical) and a matrix is a vector with dimension attribute. Example: `c(10, FALSE)` You see that R coerces the logical value to a numeric one. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I have to show the data in shiny using rhandsontable. The proble is that the number of columns of my real dataframe is 19 while the rows are only 2, so I'd like to transpose it for better visualization.

Comment: You might work with strings `t(t(sapply(xx, as.character)))`

Comment: I could but it would be great if there was a way to save the type of each column so that after editing the data I can transpose them back, reassign the right data type and finally save them.

Answer (score 1):

I got around the problem thanks to the idea given by markus

First i save the datatypes in a vector

```
dat_type <- sapply(DF, class)
```

Then I transpose the dataframe

```
xx <- as.data.frame(t(xx), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I modify it in shiny with rhandsontable and then I transpose it back before saving

```
xx <- as.data.frame(t(xx))
```

I use a function inspired by this question ([Assign data types to each column of a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067782/assign-data-types-to-each-column-of-a-data-frame-in-r)) to set the right datatype for each column

```
data.type.assign <- function(xx, dat_type){
  for(col_ind in 1:ncol(xx)){
    switch (dat_type[col_ind],
            "numeric" = {xx[,col_ind] <- as.numeric(xx[,col_ind])},
            "character" = {xx[,col_ind] <- as.character(xx[,col_ind])},
            "logical" = {xx[,col_ind] <- as.logical(xx[,col_ind])},
            "integer" = {xx[,col_ind] <- as.integer(xx[,col_ind])}
    )
  }
  xx
}
```

It's called like this

```
xx <- data.type.assign(xx, dat_type)
```

And that's all. Now I save it as a csv file. Probably there are faster ways to do it but this one does the job pretty decently.